# BigQuery - function to handle hex string

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there a way in BigQuery to convert a hex string to a decimal value?

Something like:

> select hex("ff")

Answer (score 4):

CAST now supports converting hexadecimal strings to INT64 or FLOAT64 values, even though it's not specified in their [reference](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#casting)

Here's how you use it:

```
SELECT
CAST(columnA as FLOAT64) as float,
CAST(columnB as INT64) as int
FROM table
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work, but it doesn't (I'm filing a feature request):

```
SELECT INTEGER('0xffff')
```

In the meantime, this does work:

```
SELECT FLOAT('0xffff')  
255.0
```

For integer results:

```
SELECT INTEGER(FLOAT('0xffff'))
255
```

Comment: Does not work for me in BigQuery, are you sure your answer is in the correct SQL dialect? I get the following error: `Function not found: INTEGER at [1:8]`

Answer (score 0):

Looking into the [query reference](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference), I'd say no.

You have "HEX_STRING()" which does the opposite, but all the string to number functions seem to not take hex.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the following to work successfully:
select CAST(CONCAT('0x',) AS INT64)

Note the addition of the prefix 0x as the other posts suggest.